# htaccess rewrite multiple wildcards

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have multiple directories whose files I need to be redirected to the same location.

For instance:

```
www.mysite.com/news/1998/1998a.htm
www.mysite.com/news/1998/1998b.htm
www.mysite.com/news/1999/1999a.htm
www.mysite.com/news/1999/1999b.htm
...
```

There are 250+ of them. It seems like there ought to be a way to shorten 
How would I write a rewrite rule to catch all files and folders in the directory `news`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I write a rewrite rule to catch all files and folders in the directory news?

You can use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^news/((?:1989|199[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-4])/.+)$ /new/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: that's close to what I'm looking for. In the example you provide, I would want any file in `1998` and `1999` to be redirected to the folder `new`

Comment: I should also mention that the year folder will extend from 1989 to 2014.